# Bson not declaring correct name of field declared in @BsonProperty

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, bson

@BsonProperty("name") in constructor isn't working

My data class code

```
package net.hyren.discord.bot.misc.punish.data

import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonIgnore
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonProperty

/**
 * @author SrGutyerrez
 **/
data class DiscordPunishment(
        @BsonProperty(value = "id_long") val idLong: Long,
        val duration: Long
) {

    @BsonIgnore
    fun isActive(): Boolean = this.duration >= System.currentTimeMillis()

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true

        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as DiscordPunishment

        if (idLong != other.idLong) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return idLong.hashCode()
    }

}
```

Stored value:

[image]

The correct name of output field in mongo db should be "id_long" and not "idLong"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A properly annotated class could look as follows:

```kotlin
data class DiscordPunishment @BsonCreator constructor(
        @param:BsonProperty("id_long")
        @field:BsonProperty("id_long")
        val idLong: Long,
        @param:BsonProperty("duration")
        val duration: Long
) {

    @BsonIgnore
    fun isActive(): Boolean = this.duration >= System.currentTimeMillis()

    // ...
}
```

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode. - [Annotation Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

1. In your case, the annotation has to be present on the field (or getter), so you need to use `@field:BsonProperty("id_long")` syntax.
2. As the `DiscordPunishment` class has no default constructor, you need the `@BsonCreator` annotation.
3. `@BsonCreator` requires `@BsonProperty` on each parameter

**Spring Data Mongo DB**:

If you are using Spring Data Mongo DB, the Bson annotations have no effect, but you can simply use [@Field](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations) annotation. The `@BsonCreator` is not required.